# Why does the t-test produce non significant p-values when there are outliers?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, outliers

I ran a t-test that was non-significant. Here are the data and the results.

```
Var1 <- c(12.0, 12.3, 14.1, 6.2, 2.9, 5.0, 16.2, 2.3, 4.8, 5.9, 15.0, 12.0, 11.1)

Var2 <- c(11.2, 15.1, 16, 7.2, 3.1, 1.2, 5.2, 4.1, 3.1, 11.6, 2.1, 6.5, 9.1)

data <- data.frame(Var1, Var2)

testdata <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Var1,Var2)) %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(name == 'Var1', 0, ifelse(name == 'Var2', 1, NA)))

t.test(testdata$value ~ testdata$group, mu = 1, var.eq = F)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  testdata$value by testdata$group
t = 0.45553, df = 23.995, p-value = 0.6528
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.069071  5.807532
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       9.215385        7.346154
```

When I introduced outliers (I changed the first value of Var1 12.0 to 120.0), it did not become significant as I expected.

```
Var1 <- c(120.0, 12.3, 14.1, 6.2, 2.9, 5.0, 16.2, 2.3, 4.8, 5.9, 15.0, 12.0, 11.1)

Var2 <- c(11.2, 15.1, 16, 7.2, 3.1, 1.2, 5.2, 4.1, 3.1, 11.6, 2.1, 6.5, 9.1)

data <- data.frame(Var1, Var2)

testdata <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Var1,Var2)) %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(name == 'Var1', 0, ifelse(name == 'Var2', 1, NA)))

t.test(testdata$value ~ testdata$group, mu = 1, var.eq = F)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  testdata$value by testdata$group
t = 1.0491, df = 12.594, p-value = 0.3138
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.782548 29.136394
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
      17.523077        7.346154
```

How does the t-test correct for outliers and what else is happening that results in a non-significant p-value. How does the variance influence the result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you move an observation up you impact that group's sd as well as the mean. With the Welch test you also generally pull down the df.

For two samples, of sizes 10 and 11, initially with the same standard deviation and half a standard deviation apart, here's the effect on the difference in means of moving one observation from the mean of the larger group up higher and higher, as well as on the standard error of the difference in means (top left), on the t-statistic (top right), on the d.f. in the Welch test (bottom left) and on the p-value (bottom right):

[image: Plot of effect of increasing observation on numerator and denominator of t-statistic, df and p-value]

(These are actually empirical influence functions for data values that are based off expected normal scores for n=10 and 10, shifting the second group up a little and then adding an additional observation to the second group and moving it up in multiple stages.)

As you pull an observation up higher, the t-statistic increases for a little while, but then starts to come back down and then approaches an asymptote (as indicated at 1 in the plot above). The df decreases toward the df of the (now) smaller-variance group and the p-value initially decreases but then climbs again before levelling off.

While this situation is not identical to that in your data, the basic pattern (t increases and then decreases, p decreases then increases) is fairly general.

Answer (score 4):

You’re expecting to drag up the mean of that group by having a gigantic number, right? You’ll be successful in dragging up that mean by doing that.

It also expands the variance, and that’s why you’re not getting a low p-value, despite the considerably different means.

The t-test is hard to trick with these kinds of extreme points (so-called “outliers”, though most of us on here don’t like that term).

Comment: I am fine with the term _outlier_ in the sense of Venables and Ripley "Outliers are sample values which cause surprise in relation to the majority of the sample" together with the idea that there can be outliers that aren't surprising unless you are a Martian (e.g. London relative to other British cities). What I am not fine with, and I guess you mean something very similar, is any idea that outliers are easy to identity objectively and  even less  with any idea that outliers are bad data points that must always be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You get a small p-value from a t-test (and many other types of test as well) when the mean difference between the sample means is large, as you probably expected. However, the test is looking for 'large' relative the the variability in the samples and your introduction of an 'outlier' has inflated the variability and so the scaled difference is not large.

Technically the scaling of the mean difference is relative to the standard error of the mean, which is the standard deviation divided by the square root of the number of observations.